Bootstrapped confidence interval overestimates variance in difference of means
I'm trying to translate a Welch T-test into a bootstrap sampling scheme. However, I'm finding that the bootstrapped 95% confidence interval is much larger than the Welch T-test. Perhaps this is just a known property of bootstrapped CIs?
Synthesize data, different means, variances and sizes.
A = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=2, size=90)
B = np.random.normal(loc=8, scale=1.5, size=100)

Welch T-test
import scipy.stats as stats 
test = stats.ttest_ind(A, B, equal_var = False)
test.confidence_interval(confidence_level=0.95)
>>>
ConfidenceInterval(low=1.5130925732256637, high=2.503357120571464)

And then the bootstrap scheme
def bootstrap_ci(A, B, size=30, itrs=100):
  delta_arr = []
  for itr in range(itrs):
    a_mu = np.mean(np.random.choice(a=A, replace=True, size=size))
    b_mu = np.mean(np.random.choice(a=B, replace=True, size=size))
    d = a_mu - b_mu
    delta_arr.append(d)

  d_mu = np.mean(delta_arr)
  d_std = np.std(delta_arr)
  
  return (d_mu - 1.96*d_std, d_mu + 1.96*d_std) 

The bootstrap CI invocation and result
bootstrap_ci(A,B, size=30, itrs=500) 
>>>
(1.1214979199515835, 2.862487579486028)

So the Bootstrap estimate doesn't appear to biased high or low but the standard deviation is overestimated. For reference, I had previously manually implemented the sample standard deviation function (with denominator of $n-1$) but this obviously increased variance further.
The below questions are purely one of curiosity and not of much practical importance

Are Bootstrap methods known to overestimate variance?
Are there some guidelines for bootstrap CI computation? For example, perhaps the sample size (30) and iterations (500) are simply too small.
I don't think that I've computed the standard error mean incorrectly. I don't think that $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ is necessary because delta_arr is already in terms of differences of A,B means. Not the raw populations, A or B. But is this conclusion accurate?

Thanks!
Edit:
Given comments from Christian Hennig, I've revised the bootstrap CI in the following ways: 1/ Full samples are used w/ replacement, 2/ center is assumed to be $\mu_A - \mu_B$ to avoid baking random error into assessment and 3/ the percentiles, 2.25th and 97.5th, are used to avoid assumption of normality.
def bootstrap_ci(A, B, confidence=0.95, itrs=1000):
  alpha = 1.0 - confidence
  lb_idx = int(alpha/2.0 * itrs)
  ub_idx = int((1.0 - alpha/2.0) * itrs)

  delta_arr = []
  for itr in range(itrs):
    a_mu = np.mean(np.random.choice(a=A, replace=True, size=A.size))
    b_mu = np.mean(np.random.choice(a=B, replace=True, size=B.size))
    d = a_mu - b_mu
    delta_arr.append(d)

  sort_arr = sorted(delta_arr)
  lb = sort_arr[lb_idx]
  ub = sort_arr[ub_idx]
  
  return (lb, ub)

The results are much closer to truth
bootstrap_ci(A,B)
>>>
(1.526411681562184, 2.5033789920789973)


Yes, this is well known. See Efron, B. (1981). Nonparametric standard errors and confidence intervals. Canadian Journal of Statistics, 9(2), 139–158.

Standard bootstrap should generate data sets of the same size as the original data. Your original data has size 90 and 100 for the two groups. Your bootstrap uses 30. Obviously with 30 observations your mean estimates will have larger variance than with 90 and 100.
Note also that your computation of the bootstrap confidence interval based on 1.96*d_std implicitly assumes that the sampling distribution is normal. This is not normally assumed in (nonparametric) bootstrap and the interval is constructed from bootstrap statistics quantiles (there is more than one way of doing this, see Wikipedia on bootstrap confidence intervals). Furthermore the center should be mean A - mean B rather than the mean of the bootstrap distribution (which in fact is mean A - mean B plus some random noise) if a center is used at all (the "percentile bootstrap" doesn't do that, see the Wikipedia page).

"mean A - mean B"? Would this just be the difference of two scalars and miss out on all the bootstrap iterations?

@jbuddy_13 Yes. The bootstrap is used to assess the shape and variation of the sampling distribution, but not its center. mean A - mean B is the best estimate for the mean difference that you have, so a good CI should be based on it.

@jbuddy_13 Note that the "percentile bootstrap" explained on the Wikipedia page doesn't use a center at all; it just is defined to be between two suitable quantiles of the bootstrap distribution.

Christian- I updated code to reflect your comments and what I understood from the wiki that you linked. The results are extremely close to the Welch T-test, so I'll assume that I've understood the key points correctly. Thanks for the helpful answer!

+1, though I would say that "This is not normally assumed in bootstrap" is a little too strong, the parametric bootstrap is indeed a thing (though I personally have rarely seen much use of it)...

@StephanKolassa But parametric bootstrap is not what is done in the question as data are not generated from a parametric model with estimated parameters, but from the empirical distribution. (I add "(nonparametric) bootstrap".) I use parametric bootstrap by the way: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-015-9566-5
